# What algorithms does D3.js use for the force-directed graph?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js, graph-algorithm, force-layout

I would be interested to know exactly what algorithms D3 uses to achieve the force-directed graph feature in the library. Having read [Kobourov's summary](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~rt/gdhandbook/chapters/force-directed.pdf) of the history of force-directed graphs left me a bit baffled as to what is the exact algorithm or method (combination of algorithms / heuristics) used in the library.

D3 [API reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) says Barnes-Hut algorithm is used to calculate the charges acting on bodies, an O(N*log(N)) operation. Kobourov's article mentions that Quigley-Eades algorithm, and Hu's algorithm are multilevel algorithms that make use of Barnes-Hut. Is one of them utilized in some way in D3?

The API wiki futher says Verlet integration is used for particle positioning. The [source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js) mentions Gauss-Seidel algorithm, which in turn is mentioned both in [Hu's algorithm](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v10i1/contents/graph_draw/graph_draw.pdf) and Dwyer's [graph layout paper](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~tdwyer/Dwyer2009FastConstraints.pdf). I guess the question I'm looking an answer to is what "integrative" algorithm D3 utilizes; Kobourov's article lists several and D3 force-directed features don't directly seem to fit any of those.

Comment: You best email that question to Mike Bostock…

Comment: @akuhn: I haven't seen the creator's email on D3 website. I don't it would be appropriate to email such questions directly to him, then everyone in the community would just do that. I have seen Mike answering questions here on SO so I think this is the right forum to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the original [d3 paper](http://vis.stanford.edu/papers/d3), Mike Bostock & al. wrote that Dwyer's implementation is used  for the force graph layout :

> The force layout combines physical simulation and iterative constraint relaxation [7] for stable graph layout.
>
> [7] T. Dwyer. Scalable, versatile and simple constrained graph layout. In EuroVis, 2009.

For more information, [Dwyer's paper](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/%7Etdwyer/Dwyer2009FastConstraints.pdf) describes in details the whole algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this isn't an answer to your specific question, but on his [demo page for force-directed layout](http://bl.ocks.org/4062045), he says, "Layout algorithm inspired by [Tim Dwyer](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~tdwyer/) and [Thomas Jakobsen](http://web.archive.org/web/20080410171619/http://www.teknikus.dk/tj/gdc2001.htm)."

Answer (score 0):

An overview of the Force-Layout algorithms can be found at 
  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout