# How does the following code get away with not defining initial x and y coordinates for nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Drawing your attention to the wonderful d3 example here - http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/d3js-force-directed-graph-example-basic.html, how is it that x and y coordinates are specified in the force as d.nodes.x and d.nodes.y, yet these were never specified in the first instance?

An explanation of what the x and y coordinates within the on tick fn "mean" would be useful also - is this the x and y coordinates that the nodes should move to over the duration of the force (once force.start() is activated)? With force.draggable activated do these coordinates become the coordinates to which nodes should gravitate towards?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is on the d3noob page: the initial node location is arbitrarily determined by d3.js when you associate them with the links, i.e.

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || 
    (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || 
    (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
  link.value = +link.value;
});
```

I'm not too sure about the rest of your question though. Did you mean the tick function?

I think about it this way: at each tick, the x and y positions of all the links (and/or nodes ... not too sure) change, so you need to re-draw the paths and the circles according to the new x and y. How to re-draw those things depend on your tick function.

Comment: arbitrarily determined? arbitrarily determining x and y values to me is setting x: Math.rand() or some such. There's not even a mention of x and y locations in that code?

Comment: d3.js decides where it goes, so you don't have to care about it. If you *really* want to set it, you can. 

For example, look at http://bl.ocks.org/sathomas/11550728 where the x and y coordinates of the nodes (circles) **are** set. Delete that information, and see what happens.

Comment: Plus, force layout graphs look `nice' most of the time, that is, you don't have a lot of edges criss-crossing each other. The nodes would be all over the place had their location be randomly determined, so there is certainly a method to the madness.

Comment: "d3.js decides where it goes"? How does it decide? Is it centering them all in the svg space and then using default force settings to "push" them into what look like arbitrary positions? 

The x and y positions defined in the tick function are where the nodes/links are supposed to "move to" once force.start() has kicked in correct? 

Well with force.drag in action, if, with every tick, the nodes are being dragged around, what's the point of defining "end" positions for the nodes?

Comment: Can't help you there sorry, since have no knowledge nor interest in the inner working, but you can read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917037/what-algorithms-does-d3-js-use-for-the-force-directed-graph

Comment: Thanks for the link. The key question for me is if I'm not defining an x or a y, how can I reference them from within the on tick function? i.e. setting "cx" to function(d) {return d.source.x} - there is no source.x?

Comment: Sounds like what you want to do is to control the placements of the nodes and links manually, and as far as I know, you shouldn't use force layout if you want to do this.

Comment: It's not about controlling them manually I'm happy for force to do the work, I just dont understand how it can reference an x that doesn't exist and was never defined.

Comment: As I have said, I don't know the inner workings, but here's my take on it: When using force layout, d3 will choose (x,y) coords for your nodes/edges so that it displays nicely (Dwyer's algorithm). When you drag one node, d3 recalculates all these coords according to the algorithm (together friction, gravity, etc).

I'm happy to accept that the coords are computed internally, and so to me 'tick' just takes care of the drawing (of circles and paths).

If you can't accept that the coords are computed in this black box matter, or if you want to know more, then I can't help you further sorry.